# Convergence to normal distribution

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Consider the probability distribution of the simple symmetric walk.  That is the random variable $X_i$ equals $c$ or $-c$ with equal probability and all $X_i$ are independent and $c\geq1$.  We are interested in

$$S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n.$$

We know from the central limit theorem that $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ **converges in distribution** to the normal distribution $N(0,c^2)$.

We also know that the entropy of the normal distribution $N(0,c^2)$ is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e c^2)$.

It is clear we can't tell derive the entropy of $S_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ directly from this formula for the normal distribution. This is because the entropy of $S_n$ is invariant to $c$ but the entropy of the normal distribution is not.

The [differential entropy wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) page gives a correction term but I can't understand how to apply it.

> How exactly do you apply the correction term to $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e
>  \sigma^2)$ in this example to get the correct entropy for $S_n$ as $n
>  \to \infty$?

Comment: $\frac 1 2\log_2(2\pi e n)+O(1/n)\sim \frac 1 2\log_2 n$.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you. This is exactly the same as the binomial distribution. Why is that?

Comment: Because $S_n$ *is* a binomial! (affinely transformed) I might be off by $-1$ since scaling shouldn't affect entropy for discrete distributions which makes sense because entropy of $S_n$ should approach that of $N(0,n)$ from below but some gap ($1$) should stay.

Comment: Compare this with the $Poisson(\lambda)$ whose entropy converges to that of $N(0,\lambda)$ without a finite gap.

Comment: @A.S. "entropy of $S_n$ should approach that of $N(0,n)$ from below but some gap (1) should stay."  This is really my question. What statement of convergence justifies this?  Could you possibly add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I was wrong about the gap. Entropy of $S_n$ approaches entropy of $N(0,n/4)$ exactly (and not of $N(0,n/4)$) since $S_n$ is concentrated on "half" of the integers only. This is a consequences of Entropic CLT (google it). Write down entropy for $S_n$ and use discrete local CLT (convergence to a normal) to approximate the sum. This might not control the error term properly, but the idea is clear.

Comment: Continuous entropy and discrete entropy are only loosely related. $S_n$ doesn't live on all of $R$ but on the lattice spaced out by $2c$. Because of this, to go from entropy of the normal  that $S_n$ approaches to that of $S_n$, you need to subtract $\ln(2c)$ - entropy of a $U(-c,c)$. This is your correction factor - which is zero when $c=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you. Could you add an answer then I can accept it.  Is there a specific theorem that tells us we must subtract $U(-c,c)$?

Comment: Think in terms of information needed to describe a point from a normal distribution. To approximate a point from a normal, you need to first define a point from its binomial approximation and then describe a points location in a $2c$ interval centered at that binomial pick. So we get $H(N_n)\approx H(B_n)+H(U(0,2c))$ with asymptotic equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a discrete (lattice) variable, taking values at points $y_i$, equispaced at intervals of length $\delta$. Suppose also that the distribution of $Y$, $F_Y$, converges to a continuous distribution $F_Z$ as $\delta \to 0$. Assume that $Z$ is well behaved ($f_Z$ exists, etc).

The relation between the (discrete) entropy $H_Y$ with the (differential) entropy $h_Z$ is deduced thus:

$$ H_Y=-\sum_{i} P(y=y_i) \log P(y=y_i)$$

But $P(y=y_i) \approx f_Z(y_i) \, \delta$. Then
$$ H_Y\approx -\sum_{k} f_Z(k) \delta \log(f_Z(k) \delta )=\\
=-\sum_{k} f_Z(k) \delta \log(f_Z(k) ) -\sum_{k} f_Z(k) \delta  \log( \delta ) \approx \\
\approx  -\int f_Z(z) \log f_Z(z) dz  -\log \delta \int  f_Z(z) dz $$

Hence, as $\delta \to 0$
$$ H_Y \to h_Z -\log \delta$$

In our case: $S_n$ take values at points separated by intervals of length $\delta=2c/\sqrt{n}$ And, as $n\to \infty$, $S_n$ tends to a normal $Z\sim N(0,c^2)$ (and $\delta \to 0$).

Then $h_Z=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e c^2)$ and

$$H_Y\to \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e c^2) -\ln \frac{2 c}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{\pi e n}{2}$$

(entropy is in nats; if you prefer bits/shannons, just change the base of the logarithm)

This is consistent with the fact that $H_Y$ should be invariant to scaling (hence it should not depend on $c$)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!

Comment: @A.S.  Where did you get your first formula from? Calling $H_N$ $H_S$ the entropies in nats and shannons, if $H_S = \log_2(\cdot)$ then $H_N = H_S / \log_2 e = \ln (\cdot) $ , i.e., if an entropy is expressed as a logarithm, to change the unit you must only change the base of the logarithm.

Comment: Of course you are right. I mindlessly looked at wikipedia's page for binomial distibution which is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really.

The entropy of a random process $\{X_1,X_2 \ldots\}$ is defined to be $H(X) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}{n}$. (Cover and Thomas, Elements of Information Theory, 2e). For stationary random processes, this coincides with the so called entropy rate (also defined in the former reference).

In this case, the random process is bijectively given by $\{S_n\}$ and $\{X_n\}$ so $H(S_1,\ldots,S_n) = H(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. The entropy of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is $n$. Thus, the entropy of the process $\{X_1,\ldots\}$ is the same as the entropy of the process $\{S_1,\ldots\}$ and is $1$.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding but this can't be right. $S_n$ is a random variable which with high probability ranges between $\pm C_1 \sqrt{n}$ for constant $C_1$.  We know that the entropy is therefore going to be approximately $C_2\ln{n}$ for some other constant $C_2$ when $n$ is large.  I am talking specifically about the entropy of the random variable $S_n$.  We can also guess that the entropy will be roughly the same as for the binomial distribution. This is also of the form some constant times $\ln{n}$.

Comment: So, you're not concerned with the entropy of the process, but concerned with the behavior of the sequence $\{H(S_1),H(S_2),\ldots\}$? In this case, $H(S_n) \sim \log n$.

Comment: Right. How do we know $H(S_n) \sim \log{n}$?

Comment: The OP does not refer to the (joint) entropy of the sequence $X_1 X_2\cdots X_n$ (or equivalently) of the sequence $S_1 S_2\cdots S_n$ , nor to the entropy rate of that sequence. It just refers to the (marginal) entropy of $S_n$