# What is the entropy correction term for a multivariate distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, entropy, central-limit-theorem

I wonder if anyone would be able to help me with a confusion I have got myself into please.

Consider a fixed and given $n$ by $n$ matrix $M$ whose elements are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$. Consider also a random vector $v$ whose elements are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$.

We know that  $H(Mv) = n$ if and only if $M$ is non-singular. Here $H$ is the  Shannon entropy of a discrete random variable  (in bits).

Here is my confusion. Each element of $Mv$ is a binomial random variable (actually a simple symmetric random walk)  and so for large $n$ each element of $Mv$ should converge to a Gaussian if suitably scaled.

I think this means that $Mv$ converges to a multivariate Gaussian with covariance matrix $MM^T$. The differential entropy of a multivariate Gaussian is known to be linear in $\log(det(MM^T)$.  See [Theorem 9.4.1 from Cover and Thomas](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779571945128/Differential_Entropy.pdf).

I know there is a correction  factor one has to apply when going from discrete to continuous entropy (see [Theorem 9.3.1 from Cover and Thomas](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779571945128/Differential_Entropy.pdf)).  However, we would need this correction term to somehow deal with the fact that the entropy is constant as long as $det(M)>0$. That is it makes no difference to the entropy how small or large the determinant is as long as it is not zero.

What is the correction term that deals with this seeming contradiction?

Comment: Didn't I explain this to you in the 1-D case? $Mv$ lives on a lattice-like structure where the size of each cell is $2\det(M)$. So, in unscaled terms, to $H(N)\approx H(Mv)+\log(2\det(M))$ and everything gets nicely equaled out. I might be off in terms of specific constants, but the basic principle is the same - $Mv$ is not continuous, but discrete and your correction factor will depend on $\log M$ and $n$ (due to scaling in $n$ dimensions) as expected.

Comment: You already asked a very similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583663/convergence-to-normal-distribution/1592086#1592086

Comment: BTW: It's slightly incoherent to speak of a fixed  "$n$ by $n$ matrix $M$" and then state that "$Mv$ converges to a multivariate Gaussian". It converges when $n \to  \infty$? Then $M$ is not fixed and you need to specify how $M(n)$ behaves. Furthermore, it's problematic to speak of the convergence of a vector with varying dimension (and tending to infinite).

Comment: @leonbloy About your first point. Yes your 1d answer was very clear but I have got confused about how it works in the multivariate case. A.S Says you get $H(Mv) + \log(2det(M))$ but I would love to see the math for that explicitly.  About your 2nd point, you are right. What I am trying to express is that you get an approximation whose accuracy depends on $n$ (and is smaller for large $n$). If you can think of a better way of expressing this I would be grateful.

Comment: @A.S. Yes but I have got confused about how the solution works in the multivariate case. If you could put how you get $H(N) \approx H(Mv) + \log(2 det(M))$ explicitly in an answer I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same derivation I used in my answer to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583663/convergence-to-normal-distribution/1592086#1592086), we get that, the entropy of a discrete (lattice) distribution with "cell size" $\Delta$ is related to the differential entropy of the continuous distribution that approximates it by

$$ H_Y \to h_Z -\log \Delta$$

Now, it's a know result in multivariate analysis that the change in volume induced by a transformation $(s_1, \cdots s_n)=g(t_1, \cdots t_n)$ is measured by the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables). In particular, if the transformation is linear $s =A t$ then the Jacobian is the determinant of the matrix: $J=|A|$.

In our case, we have $y=Mv$. The cells in $v$ space ($v_i \in \{-1,1\}$) have size $2^n$. Hence the cells in $y$ space have size $|M| \, 2^n$. Further, the differential entropy of a Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma=M M^t$ is $\frac{1}{2} \log[(2\pi e)^{n}|\Sigma|]= \frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi e)+\log |M|$

Then, assuming that CLT applies and that $|M|\ne 0$:

$$ H_Y \to \frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi e)+\log |M| -\log (|M| \, 2^n)= \frac{n}{2} \log(\pi e/2)  $$

Hence, the entropy is independent of $|M|$, as it should be.

Comment: Thank you! You don't seem to get an entropy of exactly $n$ bits however. Why is that?

Comment: @Lembik Because, as I pointed out in a comment, all this does not make rigourous sense. You really cannot apply CLT here, as the dimension goes to infinite together with the number of samples, and there is no normalization, and the "cells" are unbonded. Notice that my claim "the cells have size $2^n$ is actually disputable. To tell the truth, I'm surprised that the result is so close ($H_Y=1.047 n $ bits)

Comment: What do you mean by "unbonded"?  Also, why does $\log(|\Sigma|) =\log(|M|)$?

Comment: I meant "unbounded". In one dimension (my previous answer), each binomial has only two cells (in the borders) that are unbounded, but we can ingore them (they are too few, and in the region of low probability), when the dimension grows with $n$ that is not so.

Comment: $ |Σ|=|M M^t|=⁡|M| |M^t| = |M|^2$

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that if $M$ is even slightly non-square this approach can't be used (say $M$ has one fewer rows than columns)? This is because the change in volume part of the argument no longer makes sense (the new volume is zero).