# Compare differential entropy of multivariate Gaussian with different dimensions

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Since joint entropy is commonly used to quantify the average information of random variables, in order to compare the amount of information, can we directly compare the joint entropy of multivariate normal distributions with different dimensions? (e.g., one MVN with 2x2 covariance matrix while another MVN with 4x4 covariance matrix)

Comment: Sure. Both entropies will have the same units (bits or nats), so they can be compared

Comment: No. The "differential entropy" is not a "true" entropy, it does not give a meaningful measure of information content (the information content of a non-degenerate continuous variable is $+\infty$), and it's sensitive to scale. It can only be compared (and substracted) with other differential entropies in the same scale. Hence it does not make sense at all to compare differential entropies of different dimensions.

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for the reply! Is there any other good way to compare the amount of information between two random (e.g., Gaussian) vectors with different vector lengths? (note that the two random vectors are from the same source and their variance levels are of the same scale).

Comment: The "amount of information" of each vector is infinite. At most, you could say that doubling the dimension doubles the information content. See eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590790/what-is-the-entropy-correction-term-for-a-multivariate-distribution/1598243#1598243

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no operational interpretation of differential entropy in the first place (and thus no common ground on which one could reasonably make a comparison). Cf. the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256203/how-to-interpret-differential-entropy) question on differential entropy.

If you have two pairs of multivariate Gaussians, one for each dimension, then you may interpret differences of KL divergence as how much faster Neyman–Pearson hypothesis testing distinguishes one pair relative to the other, *à la* Stein's lemma.