# Differential entropy measure that is sensitive to the amount of dimensions?

Tags: information-theory

In information theory, if we have $n$ discrete bits, i.e. variables with a domain of two elements, and we have a uniform distribution over each element, then the entropy of the total system equals $n$. **This is a discrete notion of entropy.**

There is also a notion of differential entropy. Suppose we have $n$ iid uniformly distributed variables on $[0,1]$. Then we can't talk about the discrete entropy of the system, but we can talk about their differential entropy (which formulaically is the same).

However, in that example, the differential entropy assigns entropy $0$ to this uniform system, and **it doesn't depend on the number of dimensions**. But intuitively, we have more uncertainty in some sense, if we add more variables.

**Is there a notion of differential entropy that assigns entropy $n$ to a system of $n$ iid uniform variables on the unit interval?**

Comment: This might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_density_of_discrete_points

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist , I think that adapted measure doesn’t really do what I want. At least I can’t see how?

Comment: It’s not very transparent from the Wikipedia page, but, if I remember correctly, the idea is that the LDDP is the limit of the discrete entropy of discretisations of your continuous distribution, so it seems like it should give you what you’re looking for. I think there are more details in the textbook by Thomas and Cover.

Comment: @theoreticaleconomist, but that still gives you the same amount of entropy regardless of dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure? That seems unlikely. But ok, if you say so. Sorry you didn’t find it helpful!

Comment: Part of the trouble is that defining differential entropy already means that you need to fix a notion of dimension - a density is defined with respect to a given notion of volume (Lebesgue measure), and defining volume needs a fixed notion of dimension. Indeed, if your concept of volume is $n$ dimensional, then the uniform distribution on the $n$-cube has differential entropy $0$, while that on a $d<n$ cube has differential entropy $-\infty$ (since it is not a.c. to $\mathrm{Leb}_n$).

Comment: One approach might be to use some rate-distortion type idea, under a max metric. Let $R(\delta)$ be the smallest rate at which you can compress the source up to sup norm distortion $\delta$. One can then study something like $\lim_{\delta \to 0} R(\delta)/\log(1/\delta)$ (note the relationship to metric entropy), or some other function of $\delta$ in the same limit. This will recover the property you want - a $d$ fold product source should need $d$ times the rate. Note that this is deeply related to the link @TheoreticalEconomist pointed you to.

Comment: Correction - i meant fix a dimension, not a 'notion of dimension' in the above.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361364/compare-differential-entropy-of-multivariate-gaussian-with-different-dimensions